# VLOOKUP IN PHP FOR A .CSV FILE

Tags: php, csv

**I am simply trying to do what excel calls vlookup using php based on a .csv file**

***.CSV FILE is the following:***

ID;NAME;ADDRESS
123;John;999 Street
123;John;234 Blvd
999;Mark;777 Avenue

I have a textbox for inputting "ID". If I type "123" and press submit I want the following result:

123;John;999 Street
123;John;234 Blvd

This is what I got but I need help

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
      if($data[0] == '123') 
          array_push($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);

  var_dump($result);
}
?>
```

...

Comment: `array_push($data);`.... push your matching results onto a ___different___ array to the one that you're reading, like `$result`

Comment: `array_push($result, $data);` or better `$result[] = $data;`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {  
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {  
          if($data[0] == 'yes')   
         array_push($result, $data);  
          }  
        fclose($handle);  
        var_dump($data);  
    }  
    ?>
```

outputs

Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
bool(false)

Comment: Define `$result` as an array before your loop